# ODOO 10 many2many

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

I have a problem in ODOO 10 with a many2many relationship.
I have extended res.partner this way:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    x_bagsdesign = fields.Many2many('product.product',string='Bags Design',relation='bags_design_manufactur')
```

then I have extended also product.template model:

```
class product_template_fields(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    x_traders_stock = fields.Many2many(
    'res.partner', string='Traders with access to stock',relation='xtradstock_res_partner_rel')

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):

        record = super(product_template_fields, self).write(vals)  
        for singletrader in self.x_traders_stock:
            singletrader.x_bagsdesign = [(4,self.id)]    

        return record
```

This way every time a new x_traders_stock is inserted in product.template, a new x_bags_design is also created in res.partner.

BUT.. when I save a new record in product.template I get an sql error:

```
bad query:  INSERT INTO bags_design_manufactur (res_partner_id, product_product_id)
                    (SELECT a, b FROM unnest(ARRAY[1]) AS a, unnest(ARRAY[7]) AS b)
                    EXCEPT (SELECT res_partner_id, product_product_id FROM bags_design_manufactur WHERE res_partner_id IN (1))
```

I don't understand where the EXCEPT part of the sql query is coming from and how to prevent it. If anyone can help I would be grateful.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a bit different from expected, but I can fix some problems in your code. First of all you have to take into account that a `product.product` object is a variant of a `product.template` object, so you can have in a database many `product.product` objects pointing to the same `product.template` (e.g. a `product.template` is a *T-shirt* and a `product.product` is a *T-shirt colour red size M*). This means that you can't try to set the ID of a `product.template` in a field which is expecting the ID of a `product.product`, as you're doing here:

```
singletrader.x_bagsdesign = [(4,self.id)]
```

Of course, that mistake will not give you the message error you are receiving, there must be something wrong in other part of your code (I guess related to `bags_design_manufactur` model).

However, to fix the problem I told you above, you should write this:

```
class product_template_fields(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    x_traders_stock = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='res.partner',
        string='Traders with access to stock',
        relation='xtradstock_res_partner_rel'
    )

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        result = super(product_template_fields, self).write(vals)
        for prod_templ in self:
            products = self.env['product.product'].search([
                ('product_tmpl_id', '=', prod_templ.id),
            ])
            for singletrader in prod_templ.x_traders_stock:
                singletrader.write({
                    'x_bagsdesign': [(4, product.id) for product in products],
                })
        return result
```

**EDIT**

`product.product` inherits from `product.template` by delegation, this means that every field you create in `product.template` model is going to be available in `product.product` objects, so when you are creating the *Many2many* field `x_traders_stock` in `product.template`, you're creating it in `product.product` too, so you don't need to add records each time a *x_trader* is generated. Instead you should change your models:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    x_bagsdesign_prod_templ = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='product.template',
        column1='partner_id',
        column2='product_tmpl_id',
        string='Bags Design',
        relation='xtradstock_res_partner_rel'
    )


class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    x_traders_stock = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='res.partner',
        column1='product_tmpl_id',
        column2='partner_id',
        string='Traders with access to stock',
        relation='xtradstock_res_partner_rel'
    )
```

And then, if you want to access to the `product.product` objects a partner has, you can do it this way:

```
any_partner.x_bagsdesign_prod_templ.mapped('product_variant_ids')
```

If you preferred it, you could even create a new related field in `res.partner` which brought the `product.product` objects a partner has.

Comment: Thank you forvas! Yes, you're right about the problem with product.product and product.template, still as you said it doesn't solve my main problem.

Comment: I really can't understand where 'bags_design_manufactur' model can be accessed.. I haven't defined it anywhere, and it's only mentioned in my code in the many2many relationship...

Comment: I didn't realized that you had called `bags_design_manufactur` to the table of the Many2many, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you again Forvas, after revaluating my code the problem was caused indeed by accessing the wrong model while populating the x_bagsdesign field: by using product.template instead of using product.product the error disappeared

Comment: The second solution (Edit) is really good: code-wise and database-wise, because you don't need to override a CRUD function here and the relation is just one table now.